# Is there a way to dynamically change content without javascript?

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I am building out a page for work that has a section where the content needs to change dynamically on button(s) click. I know of several different ways to accomplish this but all of them involve javascript of some kind or another. My capabilities don't currently include writing script for this site so I am researching to see if there is a way to do this with JUST css before I inform my project manager that one of our javascript guys will have to handle it. So, anyone know of any cool CSS techniques that might get the desired effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could potentially use CSS's [`:target` pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo). This would require replacing your buttons with `a` elements instead, which cause your document's URL to apply a hash relating to the `id` attribute of the element you want to change.

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#foo">Click here to show the hidden <code>div</code> element</a><br>
<a href="#">Click here to hide it again</a>.
<div id="foo">This should only show when the link is clicked.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty slick (although CSS wouldn't be my first choice for this functionality in a NORMAL work environment, it's a good method to be aware of nonetheless)

Comment: When a user clicks on such link, will a request be sent to the server, or will page reload happen entirely within the browser?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use dynamic content without any scripting language, but your options are very limited. As James suggested, you use CSS. One common way is to use checkboxes and a label to control items visibility. You use this to make simple games, tab menus and more.

A great tutorial with examples you can try out is at http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/ but in essence, you'd do something like this: (from the tutorial)

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
   background: red;
}
```

Note that you have the :checked property and the general sibling selector in this example. You can get a lot more sophisticated.

Check out the [CSS Panic](http://jsdo.it/GeckoTang/4rXg) game which uses this same capability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to directly modify the content with CSS, because as its name suggests, it is specifically for style. I don't know of any tricks, sorry. I don't think CSS is actually an appropriate way to do this, because it is not good code organization (although web is not known for good code organization anyway). It should be really simple to bang out the javascript, so I recommend just doing it yourself if at all possible. Changing content with a button press really isn't a difficult javascript problem. Throw in some jquery, and you can get slick transitions, too.

HTML is not designed to be dynamic, it's simply a document format, more or less. I don't think CSS was designed for much dynamism either, just changing styles on certain events. So I think because changing content is not changing style, it is either not possible, or not a very pretty way to do it.

Good luck!

Comment: I %100 agree it is not the right way to go about it, this is more for the purposes of a prototype, interactive mockup sort of thing, smoke and mirrors and such. Looks like there are some decent hacks for this though as mentioned in the previous 2 responses. The reason I'm trying to avoid javascript is not because I don't know how to use it, it's because the company I work for is very tight with what types of editing capabilities individuals have and they don't want any script added (even a small amount) that doesn't go through the js guys so I'm just seeing if there's a way to do it without js

Comment: Sounds good. You had me a little worried, I feel much better now!