# Is it possible to change html content without using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a project where I only use HTML and CSS. Is it possible to change the content of an HTML element on some event with browser, like you do JavaScript '.innerHTML' but only using CSS.

For example using `@media screen and(..)`

Even removing current classname and appending another class on window re-size would be suitable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: Give a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830028/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-change-content-without-javascript

Comment: You can use [`:hover` in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) that responds when the mouse hovers over an element (you do all sorts of things in CSS based on hover, basically anything that can be done in CSS can change based on hover).  And, you can response to resize events with @media rules.  Not much else you can do to respond to an action in the browser without Javascript.  You can even appear to change `.innerHTML` by hiding one element and showing another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It completely depends on what action you're wanting to trigger the change on, but *in general*, yes, this is possible.

Here's an example based on width:

#### HTML

```
<div id="something-awesome"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
#something-awesome {
  &:before {
    content: "This is some great text here.";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #something-awesome {
    &:before {
      content: "This is some other super great text.";
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a fiddle to show how the example works: https://jsfiddle.net/ttLc7a4t/2/

Change the width of the output box to see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. [CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/) can only be used to set the stylying, not the content. Mixing both would be against the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript).

> CSS 2.1 is a style sheet language that allows authors and users to
>   attach style to structured documents. By separating the presentation
>   style of documents from the content of documents, CSS 2.1 simplifies
>   Web authoring and site maintenance.

That said, you can use CSS to look like you changed contents. For example, you can hide an element and show another one, or change the generated content (which is not real content) through the `content` property.

Additionally, [CSS Scoping](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#shadow-dom) allows you to replace the contents of an element with a [shadow tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#shadow-tree), but you need JS to create that shadow tree.

Comment: +1 - This answer doesn't deserve two downvotes.. it definitely answers the question *"Is it possible to change HTML content with CSS"*. Of course you can technically use the `content` property, but that doesn't **change** the HTML (as the question asked). Pseudo elements [don't even exist in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914349/how-can-i-make-generated-content-selectable), which means that the generated content isn't even real, as you already pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to change html content without using JavaScript?

You can't change the *content* with `CSS`, no.

But you *can make content visible and invisible* with `CSS`.

Here's a simple example using the `CSS` property `overflow:hidden`

As you hover over each box in the grid below, the box in the centre will tell you correctly which, box you are hovering over.

```css
div,
div span {
display: inline-block;
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
font-size: 36px;
line-height:50px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}

div {
float: left;
background-color: rgb(207,207,207);
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}

div div {
position: relative;
z-index: 12;
width: 150px;
border: none;
}

div:nth-of-type(4),
div:nth-of-type(6) {
clear:left;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
margin-right: 152px;
}

div.textbox {
position: relative;
top:-52px;
left: -304px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.textbox div {
background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .textbox div {
top: -50px;
}

div:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .textbox div {
top: -100px;
}

div:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .textbox div {
top: -150px;
}

.textbox:hover div {
top: -200px;
}

div:nth-of-type(5):hover ~ .textbox div {
top: -250px;
}

div:nth-of-type(6):hover ~ .textbox div {
top: -300px;
}

div:nth-of-type(7):hover ~ .textbox div {
top: -350px;
}

div:nth-of-type(8):hover ~ .textbox div {
top: -400px;
}

div:nth-of-type(2):hover,
div:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .textbox {
background-color: orange;
}

div:nth-of-type(3):hover,
div:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .textbox {
background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-of-type(4):hover,
div:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .textbox {
color: white;
background-color: green;
}

.textbox:hover {
color: white;
background-color: black;
}

div:nth-of-type(5):hover,
div:nth-of-type(5):hover ~ .textbox {
color: white;
background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(6):hover,
div:nth-of-type(6):hover ~ .textbox {
color: white;
background-color: purple;
}

div:nth-of-type(7):hover,
div:nth-of-type(7):hover ~ .textbox {
background-color: white;
}

div:nth-of-type(1):hover,
div:nth-of-type(8):hover,
div:nth-of-type(8):hover ~ .textbox {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<div class="textbox">
<div>
<span>Box 1</span>
<span>Box 2</span>
<span>Box 3</span>
<span>Box 4</span>
<span>Box 5</span>
<span>Box 6</span>
<span>Box 7</span>
<span>Box 8</span>
<span>Box 9</span>
</div>
</div>

</section>
```