# how to add a pop up box to a button using css

Tags: css

how do I make a pop up box when I press a button
how do I make this code work on the buttons on the image in the link I've added

```
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD018J3LMVQB
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include all necessary markup, rather than using an external link.

Comment: Please innclude your own code you have tried so far in the question directly so we can see what your issue might be. Also see ► [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & [**How do I ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: how do I add the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting You should really read all the pinned articles in the [help] as well.

Comment: i'm sorry I don't understand how to add the code could you please look at the external link I've attached and please tell me how can I add a pop box using css only to the button on the image? thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to dynamically change content without javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830028/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-change-content-without-javascript)

Comment: If you need to edit a question, you'd use the [edit] link below the question tag on the left.

Comment: @TomerKravitz `i'm sorry I don't understand how to add the code` There is help links when you ask a question. Have you tried what the different icons in the editor do? Have you hovered over them to see what they say they are for? Also, the editor itself has a ? on the top right which also has another link in the quick help that opens up after clicking it to go for even more info. Have a closer look before saying "you don't know" as there is a lot of help provided to guide new users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "pop up box"? An alert by the browser or an element within the document?

---

For an alert: you would need to use JavaScript like so:

```
<button onclick="alert('Message goes here');"></button>
```

For a box element within your document: you should use JavaScript as well, like so:

```
function popBox(id) {
  if (document.getElementById("pop" + id)) return;
  var myBox = document.createElement("div");
  // Style your div element as you wish, with JS, in <style></style>, in an external stylesheet
  myBox.id = "pop" + id;
  myBox.innerHTML = "Hey.";
  document.getElementById("imgwrap").appendChild(myBox);
}
```

Whole file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    .imagewrap {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    #button1 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 25%;
    }
    
    #button2 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    #button3 {
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      top: 50%;
    }
    
    #pop1, #pop2, #pop3 {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 3;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    #pop1 {
      right: 10%;
      top: 10%;
      background-color: #FFF;
    }
    
    #pop2 {
      right: 20%;
      top: 20%;
      background-color: #888;
    }
    
    #pop3 {
      right: 30%;
      left: 30%;
      background-color: #000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="imagewrap" id="imgwrap">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2012/opening_ceremony-2012-hp.jpg" />
      <div id="pop">
        <button id="button1" onclick="popBox(1);">אודות</button>
        <button id="button2" onclick="popBox(2);">ערוץ היוטיוב</button>
        <button id="button3" onclick="popBox(3);">פייסבוק</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function popBox(id) {
        if (document.getElementById("pop" + id)) return;
        var myBox = document.createElement("div");
        // Style your div element as you wish, with JS, in <style></style>, in an external stylesheet
        myBox.id = "pop" + id;
        myBox.innerHTML = "Hey.";
        document.getElementById("imgwrap").appendChild(myBox);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

I recommed using `button` element instead of `input` in this case as it is not a form, it is a button.

---

EDIT:

I just saw your comment saying you wanted to use *only CSS*. You would need at least minimal JavaScript. The idea would be to create your `div` element, style it as you want, and add `display: none;`. Then you would have to change that to `display: block;` with JavaScript:

```
<button id="button1" onclick="document.getElementById('pop1').style.display = 'block';">etc</button>
```

Comment: what I mean by "pop up box" is an element within the document with an option to close the element after I open it by clicing the button thankyou very much for your help all